# How to alternate colours between different buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a game show in which my goal is to alternate green colours throughout different buttons every second. This will show a cool alternation of colours through the prices.

I have tried using an if statement to check if Button 1 has a green colour, if it has a green colour, I am removing that colour and adding the colour to Button 2.

```js
function changeColour() {

  // Select all the id button
  const butn1 = document.querySelector('#one'),
        butn2 = document.querySelector('#two'),
        butn3 = document.querySelector(`#three `),
        butn4 = document.querySelector(`#four `),
        butn5 = document.querySelector(`#five `),
        butn6 = document.querySelector(`#six `);


  if (butn1.style.backgroundColor === "none") {
    setInterval(function() {
      butn1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }, 1000);
  }

  if (butn1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen") {
    butn1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    butn2.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  }

  if (butn2.style.backgroundColor === "lightgreen") {
    setInterval(function() {
      butn2.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
      butn3.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }, 1000);
  }

  if (butn3.style.backgroundColor === "lightgreen") {
    setInterval(function() {
      butn3.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
      butn4.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }, 4000);
  }

  if (butn4.style.backgroundColor === "lightgreen") {
    setInterval(function() {
      butn4.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
      butn5.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }, 1000);
  }

  if (butn5.style.backgroundColor === "lightgreen") {
    setInterval(function() {
      butn5.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
      butn6.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }, 1000);
  }

  if (butn6.style.backgroundColor === "lightgreen") {
    setInterval(function() {
      butn6.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }, 10);
  }

}

setInterval(changeColour, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="one" class="butn color">$1000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="two" class="butn">$2000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="three" class="butn">$3000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="four" class="butn">$4000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="five" class="butn">$5000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="six" class="butn">$6000</button>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Create a fixed animation function using a series of setTimeout functions and recursion

Comment: @Michael - You mean buttons 1,3,5,7 will have color while 2,4,6 won't and this will change alternately. Am i right?

Comment: Nope, 2 will have colour, 1 wont, then 3 will have colour and 1 and 2 wont have colour. Then 4 will have colour and 1,2,3 wont. Then 5 will have color and 1,2,3,4 wont have colour. So *ONLY 1 BUTTON HAS COLOUR* while others dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the index to 0, get all buttons, within the `changeColour` function, see if `index` is equal to buttons length. If yes, set it to zero. As well before applying style to current index, remove background Color of all the buttons.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let i = 0;

function changeColour() {
  if (i == btns.length) i = 0;
  btns.forEach((btn) => btn.classList.remove('greenbg'));
  btns[i].classList.add('greenbg')
  i++;
}

setInterval(changeColour, 1000);
```

```css
.greenbg {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="one" class="butn color">$1000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="two" class="butn">$2000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="three" class="butn">$3000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="four" class="butn">$4000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="five" class="butn">$5000</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="six" class="butn">$6000</button>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to do remove and add class but never worked for me LOL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what effect you are going for; are you just looking to have multiple buttons rotate through several colors?

You might be able to achieve this with [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), where you define [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) with different starting points to have a sort of "rainbow" effect.

```css
@keyframes green-anim {
  0%  { background: green; }
  33% { background: red; }
  66% { background: blue; }
  100%  { background: green; }
}

@keyframes red-anim {
  0% { background: red; }
  33% { background: blue; }
  66%  { background: green; }
  100% { background: red; }
}

@keyframes blue-anim {
  0% { background: blue; }
  33%  { background: green; }
  66% { background: red; }
  100% { background: blue; }
}

.green {
  animation: 1s green-anim infinite;
}
.red {
  animation: 1s red-anim infinite;
}
.blue {
  animation: 1s blue-anim infinite;
}
```

```html
<span class="green">Green</span>
<span class="blue">Blue</span>
<span class="red">Red</span>
```

Comment: I was able to do the same effect by creating an array of colours, and then randomly change the colours. I am not trying to do that but i am trying to alternate through the next buttons. If you see from my example, the green colour goes onto the second button and the green colour from the first button gets removed. Its like a chain of colours while the old colour keeps getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use three variables for RGB- Red, Green and Blue respectively and try to modify them by increasing one, two or all of them at the timer call. Another way to change colors is to store multiple hex colors into an array and access a different array index each timer call.